# Converting all layers to Excel using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, layers, attributeerror

I'm trying to convert all layers in a folder to excel tables and keep the same file names.  Here's what I have so far and the error I got.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/layersFolder/"

layers =  arcpy.ListLayers()
outputPlace = "C:/PlacetoPut Excel files/"

for el in layers:
    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(el, outPutPlace+el, 'NAME')
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ListLayers'

Comment: ListLayers is a `mapping` request (and a "layer" is a mapping object). Data is located in a workspace with `ListFeatureClasses`.  You'll save yourself downvotes if you always check the documentation syntax before posting.

Answer (score 1):

AS @Vince has commented:

> ListLayers is a mapping request (and a "layer" is a mapping object).
>   Data is located in a workspace with ListFeatureClasses.

That particular error should disappear when you change:

```
arcpy.ListLayers()
```

to:

```
arcpy.mapping.ListLayers()
```

but you will see from its documentation that [ListLayers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayers.htm) has a required parameter so you will have more work to do on that function, and more elsewhere, before I think you will achieve what you are trying to.

Please keep referring back to the documentation.

Comment: The layers also need to have been added to the current map document to be listed.  And the existing code treated layers as strings; bunch of problems yet to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it working.  I actually had some typos in the workspace.  Here's what I used to convert all .lyr files in a folder to excel files and place in another folder.

```
# Workspace Path
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/layerFilesFolder/"

lyrList = arcpy.ListFiles()

for lyrFile in lyrList:
    excelPath = "C:/excelFilesFolder/"
    excelFile = os.path.splitext(lyrFile)[0]+ ".xls"
    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(lyrFile, excelPath+excelFile, 'NAME')
```